# If VLookup Function that add corresponding cells if 1 range matches another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

If B4 matches a # in column A I need the formula to return the # in column C and then add...

For example: Since B4 matches A1, I need C1 (90) +E1 (3) + F4 (0) and return the value in C4.

I tried this, but it returns a REF. I am missing an imbedded formula somewhere. I also want the cell to be blank if there is no match. I am using Excel 2010.
[Updated Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC1gn.png)

Comment: You say "I tried 'this' " - what is "this"? What did you try? My first guess is you used a vlookup with a range to look in that has no $ signs in, so when you copy the formula down the range does not stay fixed and it moves outside the area of your data. But that's a guess.

Comment: Must it match a value in A from a row above the current one? What if the only match is below the current row?

Comment: Hi, I am not as familiar w/ VLookup formulas & erased the one I used but it was something like =VLOOKUP($E85,$D$5:$D$137,4,FALSE), which is incorrect. I updated the rows/columns see new attached image. To clarify & for example, I am looking to return a # in the Highlighted cell in G38. (The #s in the "ID" or Col.D do not ever repeat like they do in Col. E.) 
To do this I need, whenever a # in E matches the corresponding # in D, for the formula to find the #'s in F & I in that same row (here F33+I33 & and add that to J38 and return the # back to G38.

Comment: It would probably help readability if you did not use # as a shorthand for "number".

Comment: Did you try my answer? Did it help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need something like this in B2 then copied down, but your question is a little vague:

```
=if(countif($A$1:$A1,B2)>0,index($C$1:$C1,match(B2,$A$1:$A1,0)+index($E$1:$E1,match(B2,$A$1:$A1,0)+$F2,"")
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not as familiar w/ VLookup formulas & erased the one I used but it was something like =VLOOKUP($E85,$D$5:$D$137,4,FALSE), which is incorrect. I updated the rows/columns see new attached image. To clarify & for example, I am looking to return a # in the Highlighted cell in G38. (The #s in the "ID" or Col.D do not ever repeat like they do in Col. E.) To do this I need, whenever a # in E matches the corresponding # in D, for the formula to find the #'s in F & J in that same row (exp: F33+J33) & add that to K38 and return the # back to G38. [Updated Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbbVq.png)

Comment: This is not an answer, it belongs as a comment on the original question

Comment: Hi, thanks I cannot comment in the "comment" section w/o a 50 rep. I can only leave responses here. The tried the formula and it returns #VALUE!. Good tip regarding the "#" symbol as well. Thanks.